# Can Outlook Notes(memo) add Item on VSTO(C#)?

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto

VBA sample:

```
Set objNote = fldNote.Items.Add 
    With objMail 
        objNote.Body = "test" 
    End With 
objNote.Save
```

I do not know how to do it in C#(VSTO)

Please help.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you already have the MAPIFolder object pointing to the default Notes folder and you are just trying to create a new item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you.

It was realized by the following method

```
public static Outlook.MAPIFolder memofolder;
```

and

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            application = this.Application;
            Outlook._NameSpace mapiNameSpace = application.GetNamespace("MAPI");
            memofolder = mapiNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderNotes);
```

and

```
private void OnItemSend(object item, ref bool cancel){
            Outlook.NoteItem a = memofolder.Items.Add(Outlook.OlItemType.olNoteItem);
            a.Body = "test";
            a.Save();
```

on run Outlook 2016.